# What does it mean for a model to be inconsitent?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web

*Inconsitency* is a term I thought made sense, but after looking a specific example (below) I am confused as to what it is supposed to mean.

[image]

Looking at  the example above, why is it inconsistent that Rocky is a type of JudyGarlandMovie owner? If Judy Garland's movies are disjoint from James Dean's movies I don't see the problem.

I am clearly missing *something*/not quite understanding a certain concept (even though I was feeling really confident with everything I have been learning up until now).

Please can someone help explain the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is inconsistent because Rocky is an owner of, exclusively, movies with James Dean: *every* movie he owns has James Dean in it.

For him to *also* be a Judy Garland movie owner there must be at least one movie that Rocky owns that has both Judy Garland (to count as a Judy Garland movie) *and* James Dean (to still count as a James Dean movie) in it.

However, because Judy Garland movies and James Dean movies are disjoint, we know no such movie exists. Therefore Rocky *can't* be both an exclusive James Dean movie owner *and* a Judy Garland movie owner, so the model is inconsistent.

Comment: Okay, so I see that Rocky is an individual of the `JamesDeanExclusive` class, but what part of the model says he can only own James Dean movies? (I know it may sound stupid, but I am genuinely asking.) I see what you are saying, but why can Rocky not owl all James Dean movies **and** own a Judy Garland movie? What restriction says if he is part of `JamesDeanExlclusive` means he only owns James Dean movies, is what I am asking. And thanks for replying, Jeen, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Because the class `JamesDeanExclusive` doesn't mean they own all James Dean movies, it means that all movies they own are James Dean movies. That's what the `∀ ownsMovie all JamesDeanMovie` expression means. In words it says "for every movie that is a value of the ownsMovie relation it must hold that it is a James Dean Movie"

Comment: By the way, the syntax `ownsMovie all JamesDeanMovie`, which means in description logic abstract syntax ∀`ownsMovie`.`JamesDeanMovie`, is either an archaic version of the [Manchester syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/) that should be written now `ownsMovie *only* JamesDeanMovie`, or a mistake. I think that the notation `property  only  Class` is clearer, from an English language perspective, because it is the class of who owns only James Dean movies.